# Extracting the matched string found System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am able to deternine if the string is found in a input record using the following code but I need to extract the found string (it should also contain some addtional characters) so that I can see what I have found, because I am doing a partial search.

For example I am looking "NY" in a string which will carry city names. I should be able to get for example"New york" (Don't mind few more letters but at least I will be able to see what I found). Here is the code I am using for searching a string.

```
 if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(CityNames, CheckName, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("String Found");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("String Not Found");

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Match` method to find the match, the `Success` property to see if it found anything, and the `Value` property to get the matched string:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(CityNames, CheckName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (m.Success) {
  MessageBox.Show("String Found: " + m.Value);
} else {
  MessageBox.Show("String Not Found");
}
```

Comment: @user2026794: Add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of the file. Or right click on the word and select to include the namespace.

Comment: I am only getting NY for m.value I need to get lets say 15 characters from the found string position. Thanks

Comment: @user2026794: Use a pattern that includes more characters, like `"NY.{1,13}"`. If that's not possible, you can use the index of the match to get part of the string: `CityNames.Substring(m.Index, 15)`;

Answer (score 0):

check this code :

```
string CityNames = "N York";
string CheckName = @"(NY|New York|[^N-Y])";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(CityNames, CheckName, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("String Found");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("String Not Found");
}
```